# Scrollbar breaks up the page when trying to make sticky navbar

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a sticky navbar. So i'm adding the `position: fixed;` and `width: 100%`. It's working but scrollbar looks bad. This is the code;

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
```

When i'm adding `width: 100%` and `position: fixed;` scrollbar section is breaks up like this;

[Look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMqnt.png)

[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2r7.png)

How can i solve this?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what it looks like before? Also, it would if you posted some HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really simple. The answer is: it's the padding. as you might know by now, padding is some pixels that get added to an element after its normal dimensions and before the border. For example:

[image: padding and no padding example]

So when you set width to 100% the padding overflows your page. You need to set your width to `100% - (padding * 2)`. Padding is *2 because there is one in the left and one in the right. This can be acheived with the `calc()` function of CSS.

```
.yournavbar{
    /*Style here*/
    padding: 8px; /*Set this to anything*/
    width: calc(100% - calc(8px * 2)); /*You have to set 8 px to your padding*/
}
```

Example image:

[image: Width 100% and minus padding example]

Did this solve your error? Do you want more information (for margin and border)? Comment me.

Comment: As referenced in another question, you can also use `box-sizing:border-box` to control the padding, and the border.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like your padding is pushing your content way after the 100% size. Try using `box-sizing: border-box;` and check out this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing